# How to convert Library project into jar

Tags: android, library-project

Could any one please tell me the steps to convert the library project into jar.

Answer (score 8):

in eclipse select your library project

```
1:right click on project 
2: select export
3:java then jar
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rightclick  on `Project>export>Java>jarfile` select the files  and your jar ready.

Be sure that library project files doesnt conflict other project file. ex `Manifest.xml` your library manifest may contains activity which is already in project(your jar added) manifest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Project>export>Java>jarfile
2. remove Manifest.xml
3. remove /res